# Field <field-name> from <file-name> record (recid <RECID>) was missing from FIELDS phrase. 8826

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I get this error for some records. I read all articles of the knowledgebase, but nothing works for me.
When i connect with my local source to the remote DB everything is fine, if i use the terminal server (Citrix) the message appears all the time with the same record. It is a dynamic query without fields/except statement.
All fields of the record are filled correctly.
Someone has an idear what else can couse this error?

I use Progress Version 11.4, i also tried 11.7.

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your Progress version and the KB article links that haven't worked.

Answer (score 2):

There is a documented defect that can cause this. https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000029518

The workaround is to enable -rereadfields in production. This will mean that the AVM will reread the record to get the fields it needs to satisfy the query if they aren't available at the time of asking. It is bad practise to enable it in development and test so that you catch places where the fields phrase is genuinely wrong. But in production it will stop the users getting the error.

The defect suggests it applies to v10 and v11, so by inference it may be fixed in v12, but that is not a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to reproduce the error on my local machine.

Three things have to come together,

-a query with FIRST-OF statement,

-any error with NO-ERROR

-a function call with fields statement on the same table of the FIRST-OF

```
DEFINE BUFFER b_table FOR table123.
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

FUNCTION get_values RETURNS CHARACTER (
    INPUT id_ AS INTEGER,
    INPUT field_    AS CHARACTER,
    INPUT dat_  AS DATE
    )
    :
    DEFINE VARIABLE return_ AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO INIT ?.
    DEFINE BUFFER c_table FOR table123.
    
    FOR FIRST c_table FIELDS (wert)
        USE-INDEX abc
        NO-LOCK:
        return_ = c_table.wert.
    END.
    
    RETURN return_.
END FUNCTION. 


FOR EACH b_table  USE-INDEX abc  NO-LOCK  BREAK BY b_table.a_id BY b_table.b_id:
    IF FIRST-OF(b_table.b_id) THEN DO:
       c = ENTRY(0,c) NO-ERROR.
       cTmp = get_stat_values(b_table.b_id, "exp_id", TODAY ).
    END.
END.
```